# Erro quando seleciono o segundo dado/informação da ListView

Tags: listview, vba, selecteditem

Estou a desenvolver uma **aplicação** e estou preso no seguinte processo. A aplicação chama-se "INFORTGEI" e é para uma **loja de informática**. Quando executamos a aplicação conseguimos observar um **formulário/janela principal(*form/window*)** com um **menu de faixa(*stripmenu*)** nele(a), o stripmenu contém alguns **butões(*button*)** que abrem um **MDIparent** ou noutras palavras, uma nova janela pequena dentro do formulário/janela principal, no novo MDIparent tenho 2 **rótulos(*label*)**, com o **texto(*text*)** igual a "Código Postal" e "Localidade". Ao lado de cada rótulo temos 2 **caixas de texto(*textbox*)**. Temos também 4 butões simples, botão **adicionar**, botão **editar**, botão **remover** e botão **sair**. Ao lado de tudo que disse até agora, existe uma **exibição de lista(*ListView*)** e quando selecionas o primeiro **dado(*data*)** seja qual for nada acontece e o dado fica selecionado sem qualquer erro, mas quando escolhemos o segundo dado, seja qual for dá o seguinte **erro(*error*)**:

[image: Erro ocorrido, clique no link para observar!]

Eu e o meu professor tentámos várias possibilidades de solucionar o problema, mas nem meu professor conseguiu identificar como resolver.Irei deixar o código abaixo para quem quiser ter a oportunidade de analisar, quem sabe esteja lá o erro.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmcodigopostal

Dim connection As New OleDbConnection

Private Sub frmcodigopostal_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        connection.ConnectionString = "provider = microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=..\INFORTGEI.mdb"
        connection.Open()
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    listacodigopostal()
End Sub

Private Sub addbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addbutton.Click
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("INSERT INTO CODIGO_POSTAL (CODIGO_POSTAL, LOCALIDADE) values ('" & txtcod_postal.Text & "','" & txtlocalidade.Text & "')", connection)

    da.Fill(dt)

    limpacampos()
    listacodigopostal()
End Sub

Private Sub removebutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles removebutton.Click
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("DELETE * FROM CODIGO_POSTAL WHERE CODIGO_POSTAL LIKE('" & txtcod_postal.Text & "')", connection)

    da.Fill(dt)

    limpacampos()
    listacodigopostal()
End Sub

Private Sub editbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles editbutton.Click
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE CODIGO_POSTAL SET LOCALIDADE = '" & txtlocalidade.Text & "' WHERE CODIGO_POSTAL = '" & txtcod_postal.Text & "'", connection)

    da.Fill(dt)

    limpacampos()
    listacodigopostal()
End Sub

Private Sub exitbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exitbutton.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub listacodigopostal()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CODIGO_POSTAL", connection)
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim coluna As DataRow
    For Each coluna In dt.Rows
        listacp.Items.Add(coluna.Item(0))
        listacp.Items(listacp.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(coluna.Item(1))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Listar_Dados()
    txtcod_postal.Text = listacp.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(0).Text
    txtlocalidade.Text = listacp.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text
End Sub

Private Sub listacp_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles listacp.SelectedIndexChanged
    Listar_Dados()
End Sub

Private Sub limpacampos()
    txtcod_postal.Text = ""
    txtlocalidade.Text = ""
End Sub

End Class
```

Com isto espero ter explicado tudo corretamente e qualquer dúvida que possa surgir fiquem á vontade para eu esclarecer e conseguir ajudar quem quer ajudar a resolver o meu problema. Afinal, vocês que são os mestres de momento.

Comment: Questão resolvida.

Comment: O ideal é colocar a resposta abaixo e depois marcar como a solução afim de ajudar outros.

Comment: Assim que tiver disponibilidade postarei a resposta.